# Is it possible to get Google Ads metric data on a daily basis within a date range?

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm trying to display a bar chart that shows the performance of a Google ad between the 1st of March to the 31st of March. Each bar indicates a day in that range.

At the moment my query looks like

```
SELECT 
  ad_group_ad.ad.id,
  ad_group_ad.ad.name,
  metrics.average_cost
FROM 
  ad_group_ad
WHERE
  segments.date
BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-03-31' AND ad_group_ad.status = 'ENABLED'
```

The data I get back are totals within the range. I need the totals of each day within the range. Is there a way to get this information in one request?

Answer (score 0):

I found a segment that segments the data into weekly slices.

```
SELECT 
  ad_group_ad.ad.id,
  ad_group_ad.ad.name,
  metrics.average_cost,
  segments.week,
  segments.keyword.info.text
FROM 
  ad_group_ad
WHERE
  segments.date
BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-03-31' AND ad_group_ad.status = 'ENABLED'
```

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v6/ad_group_ad#segments.week

`segments.day` is not documented but I can see on the google ads dashboard you can segment by days if the date range isn't greater than 16 days. I'm going to keep snooping around and see if I can find how that's done.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add segments.date to your select.